# Structures in C - not printing the whole string

Tags: c, data-structures

Working on some self study in understanding structures in C.

I've made a small program that gets info from the user and then prints it back via functions.
I used two different methods of handing off the data using a couple examples in the C Primer Plus book.

What happens is that I can input the data but when it prints it back out the numeric data is ok but only the first character in each string is printed with garbage after it.

My code is below for review.  I can't figure out what the issue is.

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stats {
char name;
char city;
int wins;
int losses;
int draws;
};

void screen_print(char name,char city,int wins,int losses,int draws);
void team_input (struct stats * ptr);

int main()
{
struct stats team;

team_input(&team);
screen_print(team.name,team.city,team.wins,team.losses,team.draws);

return 0;
}

void screen_print(char name,char city,int wins,int losses,int draws)
{
// system("cls");
printf("==================================================\n");
printf("Name:\t\t\t%s\n",&name);
printf("City:\t\t\t%s\n",&city);
printf("Number of Wins:\t\t%d\n",wins);
printf("Number of Losses:\t%d\n",losses);
printf("Number of Draws:\t%d\n",draws);
printf("==================================================");

}
void team_input (struct stats * ptr)
{
system("cls");

printf("Enter Team name: ");
scanf("%s",&(ptr->name));
printf("\nEnter City:");
scanf("%s",&(ptr->city));
printf("\nEnter Wins:");
scanf("%d",&(ptr->wins));
printf("\nEnter Losses:");
scanf("%d",&(ptr->losses));
printf("\nEnter Draws:");
scanf("%d",&(ptr->draws));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` and `city` are single characters only: they are not strings.

`scanf("%s",&(ptr->name));` is invalid and will be overwriting memory as an attempt is being made to read a string into a single `char`.

`printf("%s", &name);` expects `name` to be a null terminated string, so it will print the `name` `char` then random characters until a null is found somewhere in memory.

Change to:

```
struct stats {
    char name[20]; /* Or greater than 20 if required */
    char city[20];
    int wins;
    int losses;
    int draws;
};
```

or dynamically allocate memory before populating if maximum possible length of `name` and `city` are unknown beforehand.

Change the `printf()` statements to:

```
printf("Name:\t\t\t%s\n", name);
printf("City:\t\t\t%s\n", city);
```

and `scanf()` statements to:

```
scanf("%s",ptr->name);
scanf("%s",ptr->city);
```

and `screen_print()` signature to:

```
void screen_print(char* name,char* city,int wins,int losses,int draws)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it.  So why do I need to clarify the string length in a structure and not in a non-structured char?

Comment: You do need to specify the size of string, even if it is not part of a `struct`. Are you referring to the arguments of `screen_print()`?

Comment: Doh!  I just realized that I haven't once used a char as anything other than a manipulated array. 550 pages of reading C Plus Primer and doing samples of code and I've always used int, floats, doubles or char arrays.  I thought it just automatically adjusted to the input length unless limited by the scanf() parameters. Feeling a litle stoopid now.

Answer (score 1):

You're using single chars instead of arrays of chars. Both when inputting and outputting, the system is getting the memory address of a char, thinking that it's a string, and writing to/reading from it without any bounds check. So the adjacent memory is accessed as well, even though you didn't intend to.

You're lucky that your numeric data is input **after** the textual ones, or else even those would be wrong. Since a struct will usually occupy contiguous positions in memory, it's likely that they are being overwritten when you input your strings. That "garbage" you're seeing is in fact the data in the rest of your struct, plus anything that's "close" to it in memory, until an empty value is found (`\0`, interpreted as the null char).

Answer (score 1):

In your struct, only **one** char is allocated for name and city. To hold a string, you need to specify the length at declaration.

```
struct stat {
  char city[20];
  char name[20];
...
}
```

String in C is quite tricky. It is an array of characters using an invisible '\0' for the ending. A string "hello" is actually 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' in the memory.